# ML model unexpected behavior on iOS(Swift)

Tags: python, ios, swift, coreml

i have faced strange issue while i was integrating ML model from Python to Swift.

Model :
Convolutional NN

**Input** : 1000 floats

**Output(in Python)** : pair of 2 floats

Steps :

1)Prepared model for integration(created *.mlmodel file from Python)

2)Using official documentation added it in my app

3)Tryied to use generated code

It works good, but results is unexpected :

**Input** : 1000 floats - same as in Python code

**Output** : 1000 pairs of two floats

How it possible, if i expectes output of the same size  as in Python?
If it could help - i will provide neccessary code

**UPDATE 1**

Code for model export(Python):

```
import coremltools
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(autoencoder, input_names="input_1", output_names="dense_3/Softmax")
coreml_model.save('validation_model.mlmodel')
```

And screenshot of how model looks in Xcode - https://prnt.sc/ha14ih

Comment: What are you using to convert the model to a .mlmodel in Python? Is it a custom converter? If so, can you share it? When you view the .mlmodel file in Xcode, what does it look like? Is all the metadata correct?

Comment: @keithbhunter updated(added data that you asked)